# How to implement Grpc username/password authentication. Python client, Java server

Tags: java, python, authentication, grpc, grpc-java

I'm trying to figure out how to authenticate with username/password when I create a connection and nothing found.
So, my questions:

- How to create a server with username/password authentication on java server?
- How should python client connect to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in support for username and password authentication in gRPC as this approach is discouraged from a security standpoint: see [Julien's response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/grpc-io/iLHgWC8o8UM/2PN4WaA9anMJ) and other discussion of this from the grpc.io mailing list.

gRPC provides plugins to add credential objects as call metadata, and you'd have to roll your own credentials type: you can see some information and examples at https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html#extending-grpc-to-support-other-authentication-mechanisms.

Comment: As I understand, when we create an Interceptor and send credentials in metadata, server check first metadata on first RPC call. Can I add metadata during channel creation on a client side and if credentials are invalid - close the channel?